# Redirect user in Redux middleware while using Next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, redux, rtk-query

I have a Next js project that is using RTK query to handle my API requests and I have implemented middleware that handles errors from API, named "errorMiddleware"
here is the part of implementation:

```
import { Middleware } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { setMessage } from "../slice/toast";
const errorMiddleware: Middleware = (store) => (next) => (action: any) => {
  if (action.error && action.payload) {
    const status = String(action.payload.status);
    if (status.startsWith("5")) {
      store.dispatch(
        setMessage({
          toastMessage: {
            code: action.payload.status,
            message: action.payload.data.message,
            severity: "error",
          },
        })
      );
    }
}
```

I also like to add a condition to redirect the user to "/login" page if the error status is **401**. Also here is how I added that to my redux store.

```
middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: false,
    }).concat([
      authApi.middleware,
      orderApi.middleware,
      botApi.middleware,
      exchangeApi.middleware,
      publicApi.middleware,
      userApi.middleware,
      errorMiddleware,
    ]),
```